# Is it possible to have solid light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, solid-state-physics, non-linear-optics

Is it possible to have [solid light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_light)?

If so, what would it be like?

Answer (score 5):

No because solid is a state of **matter**. Light cannot be considered matter since it is made up of particles which have no **mass** and I'm pretty sure occupy no space (i.e. photons have no volume).

**Edit:** Since photons are at the quantum level, we can't actually fathom what it would mean for them to occupy space. But on this [thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110703/do-photons-occupy-space) someone pointed out that there is a sort of photon density limit. Although this still does not mean that they occupy space, and it doesn't mean that they don't.

Comment: I do not understand the comment about occupying no space. How is a photon different than, say an electron in that aspect? I also do not understand the mention of "to be on the quantum level". Again how is that different from electrons, protons and neutrons?

Answer (score 1):

This depends upon how you want light to solid. If you want light to be solid in the way the "Star Wars" movies have light sabers, I would say no. There are however materials that trap photons so they have zero velocity. Photons are in a sense trapped, and these are sometimes called artificial black holes. The energy of the photons then contribute a tiny amount of mass to the material trapping them.

Comment: Although calling those materials 'artificial black holes' will likely lead to much confusion amongst those that don't dig deeply in to the topic before wildly extrapolating...